# Need to Display records Group By in SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

In SSRS 2008, I am developing the report that should display the records based on condition: It should give me the amt_total based on gift_type (Here, **amt_total** and **gift_type** are columns of the table). 
This is the query I am using.

```
SELECT   o110113.gift_batch_no, 
     o110113.gift_type, 
     (o110113.gift_date),
     o110113.feed_doc_code, 
SUM (o110113.amt_total)
FROM GIFT_CARD o110113
   WHERE (o110113.gift_type IN
             ('RR', 'RB', 'CR', 'RM', 'RW', 'CW', 'RJ', 'RO', 'RK', 'CI')
     )
GROUP BY o110113.gift_batch_no,
     o110113.gift_type,
     (o110113.gift_date),
     o110113.feed_doc_code
ORDER BY o110113.gift_batch_no ASC, o110113.gift_type ASC
```

And the report I am trying to generate in SSRS 2008 should look like this.

[Clikck this to see the Image of the Report that I am trying to develop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu7c0.png)

I am trying to use the SSRS expression

```
 =Sum(Fields!SUM_O110113_AMT_TOTAL_.Value,"GIFT_TYPE")
```

It is throwing me the error saying:

[Please click this to see an Error I am getting in SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjf2E.png)

Kindly provide the Solution

This the report design I have developed

[click to see the Image of report]

Thanks 
Arun

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the report design including any grouping on rows that you have in place. This kind of aggregation is very simple in SSRS as long as you have data grouped correctly.

Comment: Hi Alan
Not able to add any more images. Stackoverflow is on Weed i guess. I need to earn reputaion it seems
DOnt knw how and why I need to do that

Comment: Upvoted your question, you may have enough rep now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to do group by of your Tablix.
First you need to add Row group on gift_batch_no so that will dispaly based on gift batches.
Another row group your have to create on Gift type and in that second group type you need to set SUM of total amount it will work.

Let me know if you have any other query

Answer (score 0):

That error has to do with the scope of your sum. without seeing the data sets and assuming it is not a nested aggregate operation based on the image. you are trying to reference the column name "GIFT_TYPE" when it should actually be the name of the record set, or the appropriate scope(data region/group).

here is how scope works from the provided link below

> The value of scope must be a string constant andcannot be an
>   expression. For outer aggregates or aggregates that do not specify
>   other aggregates, scope must refer to the current scope or a
>   containing scope. For aggregates of aggregates, nested aggregates can
>   specify a child scope.

you will want to see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-sum-function) for more information

Comment: Hi
I tried to use the following method but I am getting same error. I am not able to add any screenshot to this question. I dont knw whats wrong with this stackOverflow, Whenever I try to add some images its throwing an error saying I need to earn 10 more reputation. I dont knw how these ppl add those reputation.
We need answers to the questions but these guys making it complicated